# ES6 dispose of the object destructuring left-over (object trimming)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

One nice use-case of the destructuring feature when used with rest parameters is that you can get trimmed clones.

```
var source = { w1: 'val1', w2: 'val2', unwanted1: 'val3', unwanted2: 'val4'};
var {unwanted1, unwanted2, ...target} = source;
console.log(target); // `{ w1: 'val1', w2: 'val2' }` Exactly what you want
```

However, the side effect is that your scope is now polluted with two variables that you never care to use: `unwanted1` and `unwanted2`.

If `_` meant don't care, you could do something like this

```
var {
  unwanted1:_, // throw away 
  unwanted2:_, // throw away
  target
} = source;
```

However, in Javascript `_` is a proper identifier. 
If used once in that manner (`unwanted: _`), you'll end up with one unwanted variable called `_`, which goes against the goal. 
If used more than once, like above, an error is issued:

`SyntaxError: Identifier '_' has already been declared`.

Is there any way I can throw away the undesired artifacts/variables of destructuring?

Of course, the following solutions are always available.

```
var target = {
  w1: source.w1,
  w2: source.w2,
}
```

and

```
var target = {...source};
delete target.unwanted1;
delete target.unwanted2;
```

However doing this with destructuring only seems to be the cleanest way if you're cloning an object with many parameters and you need to exclude just a couple.

Comment: what abt : `var {unwanted1: _, unwanted2:__, ...target} = source;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introducing `_`, `__`, `___`, etc to drop 1,2,3 or more properties doesn't make much difference as it still creates the variables, which *'...you will never care to use'* and moreover, it threatens to add a flavor of spaghetti to your code.

However, since you need to indicate explicitly which exactly properties you want to drop, one may consider other *object trimming* techniques, e.g.

- filter unwanted properties

```js
const obj = {prop1: 1, prop2:2, prop3: 3, prop4: 4, prop5: 5},
      keysToDrop = ['prop2', 'prop3', 'prop4'],
      
      trimmedObj = Object.fromEntries(
        Object
          .entries(obj)
          .filter(([key,val]) => !keysToDrop.includes(key)
        )
      )
      
console.log(trimmedObj)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

- make use of `Array.prototype.reduce()`, which may even give you certain [performance boost](https://jsbench.me/92k8djizps/1), compared to destructuring

```js
const obj = {prop1: 1, prop2:2, prop3: 3, prop4: 4, prop5: 5},
      keysToDrop = ['prop2', 'prop3', 'prop4'],
      
      trimmedObj = Object
        .keys(obj)
        .reduce((r,key) => 
          (!keysToDrop.includes(key) && (r[key] = obj[key]), r),{})
      
console.log(trimmedObj)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `_`, `__`,`___` or Just method to exclude: :D haha

```
function prop(source, excluded) {
  if (source == null) return {};
  var target = {};
  var sourceKeys = Object.keys(source);
  var key, i;
  for (i = 0; i < sourceKeys.length; i++) {
    key = sourceKeys[i];
    if (excluded.indexOf(key) >= 0) continue;
    target[key] = source[key];
  }
  return target;
}

var source = {
  w1: "val1",
  w2: "val2",
  unwanted1: "val3",
  unwanted2: "val4"
};
var target = prop(source, ["unwanted1", "unwanted2"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can throw away the undesired artifacts/variables of destructuring?

The only way that's also not too terrible would be to define a function that does the same thing:

```
const clone = ({unwanted1, unwanted2, ...target}) => target;

const target = clone(source);
```

The variables are still created but their visibility is limited to the function which terminates immediately.

> However doing this with destructuring only seems to be the cleanest way if you're cloning an object with many parameters and you need to exclude just a couple.

The disadvantage of the above approach is that the function is specific to a specific object. You cannot reuse it for other objects. Sure, it's rather small so maybe that's not a big deal. But having a more generic helper function might be easier to understand.

Comment: I chose to go with this approach.  For example: `var target = (({ unwanted1, unwanted2, ...keep }) => keep)(source);` - does exactly what OP and I was looking for.  +1